# Why are .htaccess RSS rules being ignored?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm in the process of migrating a blog to a new platform & server, and having trouble with mod_rewrite .htaccess rules.  So far I'm able to redirect post URLs and the root domain the the new server, but the rules for the RSS URL is being ignored.

Here are my rules:

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9]+/[0-9]+/([^/]+)/?$ http://blog.example.com/$1 [R=302,L] #working
RewriteRule ^/rss$ http://blog.example.com/rss [R=302,L] #not working
RewriteRule ^$ http://blog.example.com/ [R=302,L] #working
```

The first and last rule are working as expected, but the second rule is not redirecting.  If I type in `http://example.com/rss` it does not redirect to `http://blog.example.com/rss`

I feel like I'm missing something simple.  This is my first time fiddling with mod_rewrite. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using apache 2.0+, you need to remove the leading slash from the patterns because they get stripped by apache when rules in an htaccess file are being applied.

```
RewriteRule ^rss$ http://blog.example.com/rss [R=302,L]
```